# OpenGL multiple Framebuffer chaining and post processing

Tags: opengl, glsl, framebuffer, post-processing

I have three different framebuffer objects for three different steps:

```
GLuint fbo1;   // Step1: draw initial scene
GLuint fbo2;   // Step2: apply lens effect shader
GLuint fbo3;   // Step3: final smoothing
```

I want to draw my initial scene as a texture attached to fbo1. 
Then apply a lens-shader on that and save it as a texture in fbo2.
Then apply a smoothing-shader on fbo2 and save it to fbo3.

The code in my main render function, uses a few helper functions, and is as follows:

```
// Step1    
useFrameBuffer(fbo1, fbo1);   // src , dest
DrawInitialScene();

// Step2    
LensShader.use();             // a glsl shader program class 
useFrameBuffer(fbo1, fbo2);   // src , dest
drawQuadOnFbo(fbo2Texture);

// Step3    
SmoothingShader.use();         // a glsl shader program class
useFrameBuffer(fbo2, fbo3);    // src , dest
drawQuadOnFbo(fbo3Texture);

// Final Copy Step to OpenGL default FBO
int width = self.frame.size.width;
int height = self.frame.size.height;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo3);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); //destination
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
```

The helper function useFrameBuffer(src, dest), simply sets the source framebuffer to read from and destination write framebuffer:

```
void useFrameBuffer (GLuint fboSrc , GLuint fboDest)
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboSrc);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboDest);

    GLenum drawbufs[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, drawbufs);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);  // width, height are private to class
}
```

To apply the shader on the output of fbo1 and fbo2, I am drawing a quad with a texture associated to the respective frame-buffers:

```
void drawQuadOnFbo(GLuint fboTexture) {
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // We're not using stencil buffer now
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);

    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTexture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**The Problem:**

The problem is that output appears to be a combination of Step1 and Step3 only. Looks like the Step2 is completely missed out. You can see in the final copy step, I am copying the contents of fbo3 to the final OpenGL default fbo using:

> glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo3);

If I change this to fbo2, then I do see the results of applying Step2 (but then I don't have Step3).

So it looks like that both fbo2 and fbo3 are connected directly to the output of fbo1, but not connected to each other.

How can I fix that ??

**Other Helper Functions:**

I initialised my Framebuffers at the start of the application, outside the main render function using the method below:

```
GLuint initFrameBuffer( int width, int height, GLenum textureTarget) {


    // 1. Create FBO
    GLuint fbo;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);

    // 2. Bind it
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

    // FrameBuffer Requirements
    //   (i). atleast 1 buffer (color, depth, stencil)
    //  (ii). atleast 1 color-attachment
    // (iii). all attachments should be complete
    //  (iv). same no. of samples for each buffer

    // 3. Texture Attachment
    GLuint quadTex;  // texture to be associated to this FBO
    glActiveTexture(textureTarget);
    glGenTextures(1, &quadTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, quadTex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // attach it as COLOR-ATTACHMENT 0
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, quadTex, 0);


    // 4. RenderBuffer attachement
    GLuint rbo;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
    // attach it
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);


    // 5. Set Targets for fragment shader output
    GLenum drawbufs[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, drawbufs);

    // 6. Check that the FrameBuffer is complete
    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE){
        NSLog(@"ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!");
        return fboObj;
    }

    // 7. revert to Default
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    return fbo;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that fbo3Texture is attached to fbo3: Shouldn't you be drawing fbo1Texture to fbo2 and fbo2Texture to fbo3?

Comment: It is also unclear why your `useFrameBuffer` method binds a read buffer or why you are setting a blend function for the fullscreen quad?

Comment: You are Correct that fbo3Texture is attached to fbo3. 
And i should be drawing fbo1Texture to fbo2. 
I just tried that, and it's surprising that it made no difference !!

Comment: useFrameBuffer() is just a helper method to bind the the FrameBuffer i want to write to. To be extra careful, I bind a read and write buffer explicitly. I also  tried simply binding with glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,...); It made no difference

Comment: If it made no difference, then I would check if the active texture unit fits to what you have set your uniform sampler to. Apparently you are not reading from the texture you're binding in the `drawQuadOnFbo` method.

Comment: Sorry, I just checked again that if i bind using glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, src)  then i do see strange output, mostly my clear colour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148510/discussion-between-revolutionary-and-bdl).

Comment: Doing that is definitely wrong. You shouldn't bind src to anything, but bind dst to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`. Binding src is useless since you never perform a read operation on that framebuffer.